Unable to find windows container in my Docker desktop
I have tried all the possibilities to get the windows container on my Docker desktop.but i failed to get that.
Can any one please help me on this or provide me the steps.
I used -Swithdeamon command but i got the error message like "windows container have been disabled for this installation".so what should i do now?.
OS : Windows 11

what version of dockers have you installed? How did you install it?
I hope this can help you: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1982,
Docker Desktop cannot switch to Windows Container
BR
GR

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
